# What is the integral of the function $f = \chi_{[0,\infty)}e^{-x}$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, characteristic-functions

I have $$\int_{\mathbb R} f\,d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,n]} f\,d\mu$$

So $$\begin{align}\int_{\mathbb R}f\,d\mu &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,n]}\chi_{[0,\infty)}e^{-x}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\chi_{[0,n]}e^{-x}\,d\mu \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}ne^{-x}=\infty.
\end{align}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: As a rule, it is not good to constantly switch between math notation and non-math notation in the formatting. Basically anything that is math should be between dollar signs. I've edited to clean your formatting up, but let me know if I got anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No. $$\int \chi[0,n] e^{-x} d\mu(x) \not = n e^{-x}$$
What even is $x$ on the right-hand side?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks. I think I've fixed it to reflect what the OP actually did, although it is a bit hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not correct. You are treating $e^{-x}$ as a constant function in the last equality. $\int \chi[0,n]e^{-x}\,d\mu$ is essentially supposed to be the same as the Riemann itnegral: $\int_{0}^n e^{-x}\,dx$.

The key is that $x$ is the variable of integration. For example, $\chi_{[0,n]}$ should really be written $\chi_{[0,n]}(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Can't post a comment so I will give you this as an answer (sorry). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem